# Retrieve final query from AdapterInterface

Tags: magento2, database

This seems like it should be simple, but I was not able to find a way to do it: when using `AdapterInterface`, is it possible to get the final query that's built using the query builder?

For example,

```
$query = $this->connection
        ->select()
        ->from($this->resourceConnection->getTableName('table_name'))
        ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns('run_count')
        ->where($where);
```

where `$this->connection` is an instance of `AdapterInterface`.

How do I output (or even log) the actual query sent to MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can use this to display Query***

```
$query = $this->connection
        ->select()
        ->from($this->resourceConnection->getTableName('table_name'))
        ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns('run_count')
        ->where($where);
$query->__toString();exit();
```